# does not show error in my captcha code as security code does not match

Tags: javascript, html

```
    <div class="row">
                <div class="form-group">
                <label class="control-label col-sm-6"><i>*</i> Address</label>
                <div class="col-sm-3">
                <input id="address" class="address" type="text"   name="address" 
                onchange="IsValidAddress(this.form.address.value)" required="required" >     
                </div>
                <div class="col-sm-3">
                </div>
                </div>
                </div>
                <div>&nbsp;</div>
                <div class="row">
                <div class="form-group">
                <label class="control-label col-sm-6"><i>*</i> Zip Code :</label>
                <div class="col-sm-3">
       <input id="zipcode" class="zipcode" type="text"  name="zipcode" onchange="IsValidZipCode(this.form.zipcode.value)" required="required" >
    <br />
                </div>
                <div class="col-sm-3">
                </div>
                </div>
                </div>
                <div>&nbsp;</div> 
                <div class="row">
                <div class="form-group">
                <label class="control-label col-sm-6"><i>*</i> City</label>
                <div class="col-sm-3">
                <input class="form-control" name="city" type="text" id="city" required="required" value="">   
                </div>
                <div class="col-sm-3">
                </div>
                </div>
                </div>
                <div>&nbsp;</div>
                <div class="row">
                <div class="form-group">
                <label class="control-label col-sm-6"><i>*</i> State</label>
                <div class="col-sm-3">
                <input class="form-control" name="state" type="text" id="state" value="" required ="required">     
                </div>
                <div class="col-sm-3">
                </div>
                </div>
                </div>
                <div>&nbsp;</div>
                <div class="row">
                <div class="form-group">
                <label class="control-label col-sm-6"><i>*</i> Country</label>
                <div class="col-sm-3">
                <input class="form-control" name="country" type="text" id="country" value="" required="required">    
                </div>
                <div class="col-sm-3">
                </div>
                </div>
                </div>
                <div>&nbsp;</div>
                <div class="row">
                <div class="form-group">
                <label class="control-label col-sm-6">&nbsp;Fax</label>
                <div class="col-sm-3">
                <input class="form-control" name="fax" type="text" id="fax" value="" required ="required">    
                </div>
                <div class="col-sm-3">
                </div>
                </div>
                </div>
                <div>&nbsp;</div>
                <div class="row">
                <div class="form-group">
                <label class="control-label col-sm-6"><i>*</i> Captcha</label>
            <div class="col-sm-2">
            </div>
            <div class="col-sm-3">
        <form name="review" ACTION="playing-cards-quote.php" METHOD="POST" onsubmit="return checkform(this);">
    <font color="#DD0000"></font> <span id="txtCaptchaDiv" style="background-color:#A51D22;color:#FFF;padding:5px"></span>
    <input type="hidden" id="txtCaptcha" />


    <input type="text" name="txtInput" id="txtInput" size="15" />
    <input type="submit" value="Submit" class="btn1" name="submit" id="send">       
    </form>


    <script type="text/javascript">
    function checkform(theform){
    var why = "";

    if(theform.txtInput.value == ""){
    why += "- Security code should not be empty.\n";
    }
    if(theform.txtInput.value != ""){
    if(ValidCaptcha(theform.txtInput.value) == false){
    why += "- Security code did not match.\n";
    }
    }
    if(why != ""){
    alert(why);
    return false;
    }
    }

    //Generates the captcha function
    var a = Math.ceil(Math.random() * 9)+ '';
    var b = Math.ceil(Math.random() * 9)+ '';
    var c = Math.ceil(Math.random() * 9)+ '';
    var d = Math.ceil(Math.random() * 9)+ '';
    var e = Math.ceil(Math.random() * 9)+ '';

    var code = a + b + c + d + e;
    document.getElementById("txtCaptcha").value = code;
    document.getElementById("txtCaptchaDiv").innerHTML = code;

    // Validate the Entered input aganist the generated security code function
    function ValidCaptcha(){
    var str1 = removeSpaces(document.getElementById('txtCaptcha').value);
    var str2 = removeSpaces(document.getElementById('txtInput').value);
    if (str1 == str2){
    return true;
    }else{
    return false;
    }
    }

    // Remove the spaces from the entered and generated code
    function removeSpaces(string){
    return string.split(' ').join('');
    }
    </script>






    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-3">
            </div>
            </div>
            <div>&nbsp;</div>
            <div class="row">
            <div class="form-group">
            <div class="col-sm-12">
            <center>

            </center>
            </div>
            </div>
            </div>
            <div>&nbsp;</div>
            </div>
            </fieldset>
            </form>
            </div>
            </div>
            </div>
            <!---footer---><?php include("include files/footer.php");?>
        </body>
    </html>


my javascript code is written above html code but in this code i m writing below html code ......
```

does it effect my calling my function of captcha 
    does not show me error like security does not match?
    if i click n submit button it redirect me to the thank you page 
    what is the problem with captcha validation
    why it is not validation the match not done correctly 
why it is directly accepting the form without validating the capctha?
what is the problem n the code?
cannot identify the error pease help me

Comment: According to your code validation was working properly for me. Can you explain the issue in detail ?

Comment: actually when i m entering the captcha code ..it is not checking whether it is correct or incorrect ..i enter wrong then it take me to  directly take me to thankyou.php page

Comment: if you need full code i  can provide you

Comment: is there any server-side validation of this custom captcha of yours? If not, it's trivial for a user to bypass it (or find the answer by examining the source) if they want to. Maybe consider using a free online capchta service like Google's ReCaptcha. It works well with PHP and JS. There are others available too. I'm not even sure that what you've done is actually a real captcha anyway - it seems to just insert text into the "captcha" div. So anyone could copy/paste it. Real captchas use distorted _images_ that cannot be read by a machine or trivially copied by a human.

Comment: Please visit this codepen working example and let me know..  [Code Pen Example](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/XpPqeW)

Comment: no there is no server side validation for this captcha

Comment: @DeepakSingh In that case it's almost pointless because a malicious user or bot can very easily ignore it or cheat the result. The same applies to any other validation of your form that is not repeated on the server-side. Client-side validation should only be used to enhance usability. It cannot be used to guarantee security or validity of data because it can be easily bypassed, whereas server-side validation cannot.